# How to avoid Spring's parameter type check/conversion?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

Hi i'm trying to build my own parameter extractor + validator by using Spring AOP.

First of all, i defined a request mapping like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void ttt(@MyParam(method = CheckMethod.LONG_TIMESTAMP) Long mparam) {
    // do something here
    System.out.println(mparam);
}
```

And the AOP:

```
@Around(value = "xxx")
public Object extractAndValidate(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    Object[] arguments = pjp.getArgs();
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();
    Class[] classes = method.getParameterTypes();
    Annotation[][] annotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
    // get arguments whose annotation type is MyParam and get the argument name and extract it from GET request parameter or POST/PUT body
    // validate all params appointed by MyParam.method, if something wrong, return user the detailed error explanation.
    // if all validation has passed, then convert all parameters into appointed type, and then send them to pjp to proceed.
    return pjp.proceed(arguments);
}
```

The big problem is Spring automatically identifies the parameter name from RequestMapping method, and trying to map(and type converting) GET parameter into corresponding parameter, even if i did not declare any Spring annotations for the parameter. For example, "/hello?mparam=jwoijf" will simply return a default tomcat 400 error describing "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.", and there are WARN level debug logs which says spring cannot convert String "jwijf" into Long value. So how do I avoid this kind of Spring feature?

The reason why i don't want to use `@ModelAttribute` and `@Valid` way to extract params and validate them is:

1. Using ModelAttribute will make me create too many models(every request for a model).
2. Some model attributes are identical, some are not even if they have the same name.
3. Teammates will have to know how each attribute is restricted in order to create a new ModelAttribute.

Comment: Actually, it's not good idea to have params with same name and different type of value.

Comment: ok, it seems i can add RequestParam(required = false), but i really don't want to add two annotations(RequestParam and MyParam) for each of my parameters...

Comment: @KenBekov yes you are right, they are not different types but different validation strategy, for example, a "mode" parameter for search user is allowed from 1 to 3, but "mode" parameter for search items is only allowed from 1 to 2

Comment: So you basically want to work around the framework and also give up proper OO and on how spring by default works (you cannot teach them Spring MVC anymore because you have your own solution now). Don't use AOP for that create your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which knows what to do with that annotation.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks! I think this is basically just what I needed!